# I got ClassNotFoundException when i tried to switch spring to use load time weaving

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I've added a `<context:load-time-weaver/>` in my application context. And i've added necessary libraries and javaagent to my pom.xml

Then i got following error

```
2014-05-23T17:48:11.549+0600  SEVERE  Unable to find class 'com.myproject.dao.impl.BlobDataDaoTest$' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myproject.dao.impl.BlobDataDaoTest$ not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:402)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:376)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:107)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:485)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:326)
```

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved when i've updated aspectj version from 1.6.12 to 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the weaver cannot find at least some of your application classes. This must be a class-loading issue. Maybe your aop.xml is not in the right location or configured in a wrong way - hard to tell with so little information.

Comment: What additional information can i tell you? It's appear also when i run test. I haven't created a aop.xml file. Is it necessary?

Comment: Sure. If you want to use load-time weaving, you need to configure it. I recommend you to RTFM, e.g. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07s08.html.

Answer (score 0):

There are external dependencies in my tests. They imported because in my tests i mock its. This `Unable to find class` errors all about this external classes.

```
2014-05-27T14:26:37.517+0600  SEVERE  Unable to find class 'com.aydar.pj.model.refbook.RefBook$' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aydar.pj.model.refbook.RefBook$ not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:402)

...

2014-05-27T14:26:37.517+0600  SEVERE  Unable to find class 'com.aydar.pj.model.refbook.RefBook$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aydar.pj.model.refbook.RefBook$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:402)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:376)

...

2014-05-27T14:26:37.516+0600  SEVERE  Unable to find class 'com.aydar.pj.model.refbook.RefBook$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aydar.pj.model.refbook.RefBook$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$ not found - unable to determine URL
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:402)
```